# Obtain list of ACTIVE regions only | boto3 | AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-regions

So as you know, there are several ways to list available regions using boto3 client

For instance:

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')
ec2.describe_regions()['Regions']
 
or

session = Session()
available_regions = session.get_available_regions("ec2", partition_name='aws')
```

But this will list all the regions, and most of them are in-active meaning they cannot be used for any operations

Example of a section in AWS billing dashboard:

[image: Example of a section in billing dashboard:]

I just wanted to find out how I can get the list of all "active" AWS regions using boto3

Comment: Did you get the solution for this? Similarly I'm trying to get all the active AWS services in a aws account. Could you help me on this?